# How to reflect changes in view without refreshing a page?

Tags: ajax

I am using MySQL database and hibernate and jsp,using hibernate i am reading database and prepare a view using jsp.it done but i want to make sure that any changes on database is also reflected on my prepared view without refreshing a page.please provide some clear idea to do that.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make ajax call to your servlet

start with this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/edu/ajax/tutorials/ajax-tutorial.html)